# ¿Se puede cancelar la recompensa que ofrecí en una pregunta?

Tags: soporte, recompensas

Suponiendo que formulo una pregunta y después de varios días me da la opción de agregar una recompensa (*ya que la pregunta no ha tenido mucha atención*), y decido agregar la recompensa, la cual se me es descontada de mi reputación.

**¿Hay alguna manera de eliminar esa recompensa y que mi reputación se me sea devuelta?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No es posible cancelar una recompensa. La reputación que te han quitado ya no puede ser devuelta de ninguna forma.

Por eso cuando vas a agregar una recompensa te sale un mensaje de advertencia diciendo justo lo que acabo de decirte.

Esto se hace para prevenir que atraigas atención (y posibles votos positivos) debido a la recompensa y luego la canceles y recuperes tu reputación. Sería un poco injusto con los que no ofrecen recompensas y no atraen atención suficiente a sus preguntas.

Comment: Estaría interesante, al menos, cancelar la recompensa y que no devuelvan la reputación, o que devuelvan la mitad.

Comment: mi pregunta no ha llamado la atención ni dando una reputación de 250, estaba buscando si la podía subir, pero al parecer no es posible...